kafka consumer group lag
I have a kafka cluster and there are some jvm's collected to read messages from this kafka cluster. I have closed some of these jvms to never open them again and there is lag accumulation in the consumergroups of these closed jvms in kafka, what should I do for this? Is it necessary to delete these consumer groups and will the number of lags be an issue?
Thanks.

If you never plan on starting any consumers in those groups again, lag is not an issue. It's not affecting other consumers.
Consumer groups will automatically be removed after about a week, based on the retention period of the consumer offsets topic
